# How to unit-test a requirement that can be enforced by the compiler

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, tdd

Let me explain! I'm trying to implement some DDD in a node app. I have a `Post` object with a `title` attribut. The requirement is that we can't create a `Post` with empty `title` (title is required).

I have `"strict": true` in my `tsconfig.json` file. (Enable strict null checks)

The `Post` class look like this :

```
export class Post {

    private title: string;

    constructor(title: string) {
        this.title = title;

        if (!this.title) {
            throw new Error('Post title should not be empty');
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler will stop me from doing `new Post(null);` which is good.

My question is, in my unit testing, how could I test that this requirement is fulfilled. Should I ignore it ? What if someone changed the `Post` class and make the title optional in the future ?

Comment: Presumably they'd only make that change because title is no longer required, in which case the test that claims it's required would be redundant anyway.

Comment: This is just a simplified example. What if someone made it optional "by mistake"

Comment: Then what *problem* would that cause? All of the existing code was already passing the title argument, and their new code will presumably fail the tests at some other point (e.g. not sending a valid request to an API because it doesn't have a title). The compiler will complain about all the places existing code was *accessing* the name, too, it's not exactly something they could do without intent.

Comment: So you suggest to not bother with such scenario ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I didn't make that explicit! Yes, I wouldn't have that unit test. Also note you can use *parameter properties* to simplify your existing code: `constructor(private title: string) { ... }`.

Comment: I can't agree with @jonrsharpe here. Unit testing is all about how your app will behave at runtime. Typescript at runtime = javascript = no type check. Every piece of code you didn't bother testing properly only because "type safety gets you covered" will be susceptible to cause mayhem in the most unsuspected ways.